# SpriteKit sound memory consumption issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, sprite-kit

In an attempt to further familiarize myself with SpriteKit, I made a simple little app that would spawn a random (3 choices) ball at whatever location you click or touch (which automatically despawn after 7 seconds), then apply physics and gravity, and finish with manipulating gravity at set intervals. It was simple enough and worked quite well. However, I decided to add sound to it so the balls would make noise when hitting both the walls or each other.

While it *worked*, it brought up an issue I couldn't figure out on my own: the soundless version would lag if you spawned so many balls it couldn't handle it, but the sound version continued to lag thereafter. I checked out Xcode's trusty Debug Navigator and found that the memory of the app continued to expand with every ball added to the scene. The soundless version didn't expand on the memory NEARLY as much and additionally reclaimed some bits after the balls had been removed from their parents.

I can't help but think there was something wrong in my implementation that's not only keeping the sound files around in memory after they've been used, but keeping multiples of each file.

I'll happily share my project with anyone who requests, but this is the approximation of the methods that happen:

initialization, sound actions are created and stored in the scene class so they can be accessed later:

```
@interface REP_Balls () {
    SKAction* ballSound01;
}
@end

@implementation REP_Balls {
...
...
...
-(void) setUpSounds {
    NSArray* array = @[ @"ball_hit_01.wav",]; //I have more in the array, I'm just simplifying code for stackoverflow

    ballSound01 = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:[array objectAtIndex:0] waitForCompletion:NO];

}
```

I then have a contact listener activate a method that randomizes from the available sound actions and returns one of them:

```
-(void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

firstBody = contact.bodyA;
secondBody = contact.bodyB;

SKAction* randomSound;
//blah blah blah if categories match and whatnot, do this:
        REP_BallSpawn* ball = (REP_BallSpawn*) firstBody.node;
        randomSound = [self soundBankRandomizer:YES];

        [ball runAction:randomSound];
```

And the method that randomizes:

```
-(SKAction*) soundBankRandomizer:(BOOL)isWallHit {
NSArray* array;
switch (isWallHit) {
    case YES:
        array = @[ //according sound actions
              ];
        break;

    case NO:
        array = @[
                ballSound01, //and other sound actions
                  ];

    default:
        array = @[
                  //if neither case is true somehow, just choose from a bank of all sound actions
                  ];
        break;
}

int randomChoice = arc4random() % [array count];    
SKAction* sound = (SKAction*)[array objectAtIndex:randomChoice];
return sound;
}
```

Beyond that, after 7 seconds the balls automatically despawn themselves, and I would assume any children with them (which I also assume should include actions, such as sound actions).

I even made a method to confirm no nodes are sticking around after they despawn:

```
[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"//*" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  (())(())  %@", string, node];
    }];
```

The result is then copied to the clipboard which results in a list of all nodes and children in the scene at the moment. (the "  (())(())  " is in there for a unique pattern to search for in find/replace to make new lines)

Edit: I also noticed that CPU usage remains high after everything has despawned as well.

Please tell me I did something wrong!

===================================================

So I made some changes to my code. As mentioned below, I got it to work right, but upon some further testing, it appears to be finicky as to how exactly it gets implemented. Maybe someone else will see why, but it makes no sense to me.

**METHOD THAT WORKS**

Same as above with these changes:

```
-(void) setUpSounds {

NSArray* array = @[
                  @"ball_hit_01.m4a",
                  @"ball_hit_02.m4a",
                  @"ball_hit_03.m4a",
                  @"ball_hit_04.m4a",
                  @"wall_hit_01.m4a",
                  @"wall_hit_02.m4a",
                  @"floor_hit_01.m4a",
                  @"floor_hit_02.m4a",
                  ];


SKAction* ballSound01 = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:[array objectAtIndex:0] waitForCompletion:NO];
    // etc


sounds = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ballSound01, ballSound02, ballSound03, ballSound04, wallSound01, wallSound02, floorSound01, floorSound02, nil]; //is declared class wide

}



 -(SKAction*) soundBankRandomizer:(BOOL)isWallHit {

int randomChoice = arc4random() % ([sounds count] / 2);

if (isWallHit) {
    randomChoice += ([sounds count] / 2);
}

return [sounds objectAtIndex:randomChoice];
}
```

The contact listener is nearly identical (I removed the casting for the ball and applied the action to the world node instead). I've also tried it using a dictionary instead of an array and it works fine.

**METHOD THAT DOESN'T WORK FOR SOME REASON**

I would remove the soundBankRandomizer method, as well as remove any action calls from the contact listener. Instead, I added this method:

```
-(void)playSound:(BOOL)isWallHit {

int randomChoice = arc4random() % ([sounds count] / 2);

if (isWallHit) {
    randomChoice += ([sounds count] / 2);
}

SKAction* randomSound = [sounds objectAtIndex:randomChoice];

[bgNull runAction:randomSound];

}
```

and then called it from the contact listener via:

```
[self playSound:YES]; //for wall hit
[self playSound:NO]; //for ball on ball action
```

For some reason, this resulted in the exact same performance issues I had initially. Does it make sense to anyone?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple issues....By declaring the SKAction ballSound01 it'll stick around to be used again. Also I follow your thinking that by removing every node, it would remove every action, but again I think by declaring it, that won't happen. Also SKActions could be applied to multiple nodes, so I don't think you can really consider them children of the object they run on.

I think you are better off declaring an array which holds onto those SKActions, instead of creating it each time in the soundBankRandomizer.

Also I've never seen a switch statement with a bool variable like that. Just doing this...

```
 if (isWallHit == YES) {

 } else{

 }
```

Is more to the point because the default block is never going to run anyway. Since isWallHit is either YES or NO, those two conditions are it, no need for the default.

You might want to consider making a Singleton class as a sound manager and keeping it totally separate from the nodes. So instead of calling...

```
randomSound = [self soundBankRandomizer:YES];  
[ball runAction:randomSound];
```

You could call something like...

```
[[SoundManager sharedSounds] playRandomWallSound];
```

No need to make a specific node part of playing the sound.

Comment: I worked out a solution! First, I followed your suggestion to declare an array instead of duping every action into an array every time. While that didn’t fix the problem as a whole, I expect it was not only better practice, but saved some memory. But then, inspired by your suggestion of having a singleton manage the sound (which sounds like it’d be a better solution long term) I instead applied all the sound actions to the background null object (myWorld or etc). It works now! Memory and cpu usage return to normal levels after everything despawns though! AND THATS WHAT MATTERS!